# LabVIEW: (un)bundle by name with swapped colors

Tags: labview

In LabVIEW 2017, one field of an `(un)bundle by name` is sometimes displayed with back and foreground color swapped, as shown below.

This isn't just an artefact, since it also appears after starting LabVIEW and loading a project, before running any VI.

Any idea what that means?

[image]

Comment: Which LabVIEW version do you use?

Comment: @kosist  Updated - 2017!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean anything and it is just a display artifact. It might just be some internal flag which was set incorrectly on the terminal for some reason or a display glitch which happened when the terminal was hovered over and it got stuck. From my experience you can usually just ignore things like this, but if hovering over it doesn't make it go away, you can probably also just delete it and recreate it.

I suppose in theory it could also mean your VI was corrupted somehow, but I don't recall seeing such problems after seeing these display artifacts.